# Online compiler/server to run big programs

Tags: web-services, fractals

I've written a program to generate a fractal, but my computer would take a week to compute it. Is there any online or otherwise, solution where I can run my code and have it compute quickly?

Comment: The buzzwords you are looking for are "cloud computing".  I can't vouch for any particular virtual-CPU provider being geared specifically for heavy number crunching, though.  Also, are you sure you have squoze all possible cycles and parallelism out of your program already?

Comment: what do you mean by cycles and parallelism?

Comment: How big is that fractal? My computer can calculate a 10kx10k pixel fractal easily. I don't want to be rude but I think there is some room for improvement in your code.

Comment: Try a deep zoom Buddhabrot

Comment: This is a 500 megapixel Buddhabrot with deep iteration (millions). Took 16 hours on an 8 core machine: http://erleuchtet.org/2010/07/ridiculously-large-buddhabrot.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not to be rude and don't take this wrong. Nobody is going to let people use there full computer's resources over the web to let you run code, it will always be slower online. For free. 
However VPS and Cloud-Computing options are available. They will be expensive for a really fast computer.